# Prevent ConcurrentModificationException when creating ArrayList from LinkedHashSet

Tags: java, collections, concurrency

We are performing a load testing / benchmark of a banking application. We are getting `ConcurrentModificationException` as one of the errors when running with around 100 virtual users. Below is the stacktrace:

```
java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
    at java.util.LinkedHashMap$LinkedHashIterator.nextEntry(LinkedHashMap.java:373)
    at java.util.LinkedHashMap$KeyIterator.next(LinkedHashMap.java:384)
    at java.util.AbstractCollection.toArray(AbstractCollection.java:124)
    at java.util.ArrayList.<init>(ArrayList.java:131)
    at my.package.AuthorizationHelper.getAuthModuleList
```

Below is the section in `getAuthModuleList()` which is causing the exception:

```
private static final LinkedHashSet MODULE_SET = new LinkedHashSet();

public static List getAuthModuleList(..)
{
   MODULE_SET.clear();
   ....

   MODULE_SET.add(getAllrequiredModules());

   List userLevelModules = getAllUserLevelModules();

   if (userLevelModules != null) {
      MODULE_SET.addAll(userLevelModules);
   }

   userLevelModules = new ArrayList(MODULE_SET); //Exception here
   return userLevelModules;
}
```

Modules need to be executed in order with required ones first, hence using `LinkedHashSet`.

Following is my understanding of the cause for the CME:

1. Transaction for user A calls this method.
2. At the same time, user B has also called this method.
3. By the time user A reaches the exception line, concurrent access by user B has already mutated `MODULE_SET`.
4. Because of the above, the implementation of the ArrayList throws the exception.

How the code should be modified to prevent the above without breaking functionality as per my understanding:

Change this line:

```
userLevelModules = new ArrayList(MODULE_SET);
```

To this snippet:

```
LinkedHashSet moduleSetCopy = new LinkedHashSet(MODULE_SET);
// userLevelModules = new ArrayList(MODULE_SET);
userLevelModules = new ArrayList(moduleSetCopy);
```

So my questions are,

- Is my analysis correct?
- Should I make a **synchronized** copy using one of the Collections methods or is a normal copy enough?

Note that the application uses **Oracle JRockit(R) (build R28.2.5-20-152429-1.6.0_37-20120927-1915-windows-x86_64, compiled mode)** and not the standard Sun JDK. We need to simulate production level environment hence not using the latter.

**UPDATE**: Not sure if relevant to answering, but `MODULE_SET` is being cleared at the start of the method.

Comment: You can get a `ConcurrentModificationException` from any of the modifications of MODULE_SET too. Basically you need to synchronize the entire method.,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ouch, hopefully it is not my bank that is going to use this application ;-)

Anyway, you are modifying a shared resource (MODULE_SET) without proper synchronization or locks, and yor analysis is correct. The solution, however, is to not use the shared resource at all if the list of modules is user or request dependent, or initialize it once if it is a true singleton.

For the first alternative, the code could look like this:

```
public static List getAuthModuleList(..)
{
    LinkedHashSet MODULE_SET = new LinkedHashSet();

    MODULE_SET.add(getAllrequiredModules());
    List userLevelModules = getAllUserLevelModules();

    if (userLevelModules != null) {
       MODULE_SET.addAll(userLevelModules);
    }
    userLevelModules = new ArrayList(MODULE_SET); //Exception here
    return userLevelModules;
 }
```

Comment: The `MODULE_SET` is being cleared at the start of the method. So, technically it's not actually being used as a shared resource. The exception I think because it is a `static final` reference? Apologies if this is relevant as I did not mention it in the question...

Comment: @Vrushank clearing is not enough. Consider the case when two threads execute `getAuthModuleList()` simultaneously. They're still using the same MODULE_SET.

Comment: Yes, the exception occurrs because MODULE_SET is `static` (only one instance, hence shared), and that several threads are simultaneously modifying its content. If you make MODULE_SET a local variable, the exception will go away (at least that one).

Comment: @kiheru and forty-two : You're right, I didn't consider that case.

Comment: Creating a copy didn't work. Making MODULE_SET a local variable did.